# Procurar imagem no código HTML

Tags: c#, html

Em um form, vou realizar uma pesquisa de imagens no **Bing** (em segundo plano) assim:

```
titulo.Text = "sou doador"
string minhaBusca = titulo.Text + " app";
minhaBusca = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + minhaBusca;
```

Daí quero pegar no código fonte [dessa página](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=sou%20doador%20app) o link das 3 primeiras imagens, para isso preciso buscar no código fonte por:
`.jpg` ou `.png`.
Sei que há um padrão na página no **Bing**, que o link da imagem fica dentro de uma div `item`:

```
<div class="item"><a href="http://vmulher4.vila.to/interacao/4004739/doacao-de-sangue-eu-sou-um-doador-e-voce-57209-1.jpg" class="thumb" target="_blank" h="ID=images,5012.1">
```

Como faço para pegar os três links do `href` e armazenar em um array ou variável? E para exibi-las no meu formulário?

Comment: eu acessei a página que vc colocou como link e não encontrei a estrutura que vc aponta... achei um div com a class `dg_u` e dentro dela o thumb da foto...

Comment: Na linha 17, tem a div `item`, realmente notei também que todo a de imagem tem a classe `thumb` daí seria mais fácil pegar o elemento, mas como? kk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente é necessario instalar um pacote do NUGET no seu projeto, chamado [HtmlAgilityPack - Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack), ele que vai te ajudar nisso!.

Apos isso o **HtmlWeb** do código abaixo estará disponível no seu projeto para uso.

Utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
  <img src="valor da lista aqui dentro ex: http://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Meea6e108be6309f544bab7a1....">
```

Codigo em c#:

```
titulo.Text = "sou doador";
string minhaBusca = titulo.Text + " app";
string url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + minhaBusca;
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);


       var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='imgres']"); //pega o que tendo dentro da div que tem a classe 'imgres'

        List<string> ListaImagens = new List<string>(); // cria a lista que vai guardar os links
        if (div != null) // verifica se a div achada anteriormente nao e nula.
        {

            foreach (HtmlNode type in div.Descendants("a")) // pego todos as tags <a> dentro da div, e percorre cada um (objeto type)
            {
                ListaImagens.Add(type.Element("img").Attributes["src2"].Value); //adiciono na lista o elemento 'img' dentro de 'a', e pego o valor do atributo 'src2' do elemento 'img'
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ops! Não retornou imagem nenhuma!");
        }
```

Lembre-se de estar utilizando os seguintes assemblies la em cima:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack; //do pacote nuget!
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Os valores estarão dentro da lista ListaImagens.
Ai é so utilizar como te mostrei no exemplo de tag IMG do HTML

Comment: Muito bom, tinha pensado em usar esse pacote, mas não sabia por onde iniciar.. esse `"//div[@class='imgres']"` quer disser o que procurar na página? Exemplo, quero pegar o parâmetro `href` de todas (ou tres primeiras) tags `a` que têm a classe `thumb` como ficaria? Onde eu alteraria? Isso que não entendi direiro

Comment: Esse código é um pouco complicado mesmo... pois voce precisa utilizar os metodos do pacote que te passei até achar o link. entrando dentro de nós, etc. Vou comentar o maximo que consigo te explicar, porem o codigo esta pegando as imagens que vc me referiu e colocando na lista, é so pegar os 3 primeiros elementos da lista. E utilizar como te falei.
No bing, ele não disponibiliza a imagem em formato JPEG, PNG,etc... apenas um link de referencia. oque é um tanto chato.